# NASM programming - `int0x80` versus `int 0x80`

Tags: assembly, syntax, interrupt, nasm

I have a simple NASM program which only invokes `sys_exit`:

```
segment .text
    global _start
    _start:
        mov eax, 1 ; 1 is the system identifier for sys_exit
        mov ebx, 0 ; exit code
        int 0x80 ; interrupt to invoke the system call
```

When I first wrote it, I made a mistake and forgot the space between `int` and `0x80`:

```
        int0x80
```

... but the program still compiled without problem!

```
[prompt]> nasm -f elf MyProgram.asm
[prompt]> ld -o MyProgram MyProgram.o
```

It just gave me a segmentation error when I ran it!

```
[prompt]> ./MyProgram
Segmentation fault
```

So what does this program - the original one I wrote, with the missing space - do? What does `int0x80` (with no space) mean in NASM?

```
segment .text
    global _start
    _start:
        mov eax, 1
        mov ebx, 0
        int0x80 ; no space...
```

Comment: What happens if `int 0x80` is called after?

Comment: @pst - Good idea! * tries it * It seems to execute normally! Even if I add a `sys_write` system call to make it a "Hello World" program... it's like the `int0x80` isn't even there :O

Comment: You mean the segmentation error disappears?

Comment: @BoltClock - Yes! The seg error is probably because `int0x80` doesn't interrupt and thus doesn't invoke the system call `sys_exit`... so execution continues past the end of the program into the unknown regions of memory, resulting in a seg error. That still leaves the question though: what is `int0x80` and shouldn't it not-compile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NASM is giving me this warning:

> warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error

Apparently the typo gets treated as a label and you can reference the new `int0x80` label in your program as usual:

```
segment .text
    global _start
    _start:
        mov eax, 1 ; 1 is the system identifier for sys_exit
        mov ebx, 0 ; exit code
        int0x80 ; interrupt to invoke the system call

        jmp int0x80 ; jump to typo indefinitely
```

---

NASM supports labels without colon, I often use that for data declarations:

```
error_msg   db "Ooops", 0
flag        db 0x80
nullpointer dd 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a colon at the end of this line:

```
Segment .text:

global _start
_start:
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int0x80 ; no space...
```